# How to chain joins in Sequel as in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a model "MyModel" with the following relationships:

```
Class MyModel

    #if MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one a
    has_one b

    #if MyModel < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one a
    many_to_one b

end
```

With ActiveRecord:

```
MyModel.joins(:a, :b)
```

or

```
MyModel.joins(:a).joins(:b)
```

gives the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_models INNER JOIN bs ON bs.id = my_models.b_id INNER JOIN as ON a.id = my_models.a_id
```

But with Sequel:

```
MyModel.join(:as, id: :a_id).join(:bs, id: :b_id)
```

gives the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_models INNER JOIN bs ON bs.id = my_models.b_id INNER JOIN as ON a.id = bs.a_id
```

Why does `join` use the last joined table's name?  How do I get the same SQL generated by ActiveRecord in Sequel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in Sequel's `join`, the implicit qualifier is the last joined table.

So,

```
MyModel.join(:as, id: :a_id).join(:bs, id: :b_id)
```

equals:

```
MyModel.join(:as, id: :a_id).join(:bs, id: Sequel[:as][:b_id])
```

Use an explicit qualifier:

```
MyModel.join(:as, id: :a_id).join(:bs, id: Sequel[:my_models][:b_id])
```

This is from the official Sequel IRC chat with @jeremyevans.